# Running PyTorch Model on PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pytorch

I am trying to run a PyTorch model on a GPU using PySpark. But I am getting an error about GPU memory which is:

```
return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. 
Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 56.20 MiB already allocated; 18.75 MiB free; 58.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch) 
If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.
```

Just to make sure things are working I am trying to run dummy input through the model. The code snippet is:

```py
import torch
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf


appName = "PySpark Test"
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
conf.set("spark.executorEnv.LD_PRELOAD", "libnvblas.so")
conf.set("spark.executor.resource.gpu.amount", "1")
conf.set("spark.spark.task.resource.gpu.amount", "1")
conf.set("spark.executor.cores", "2")
conf.set("spark.executor.num", "1")
conf.set("spark.rapids.sql.enabled", "true")

# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

def load_model(device):
    # Load model and put it on device then return it.
    return model

def run_dummy_model(i):
    assert torch.cuda.is_available()
    # Just trying to pass random input through the model
    t = torch.rand(1, 3, 128, 128)
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    model = load_model(device)
    t.to(device)
    outputs = model(t)
    return outputs

input = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([0] * 10)
result = input.map(run_dummy_model)
print(result.take(10))
```

Maybe also useful to know:

- The code is being run on a GCP Dataproc cluster with a single GPU node.
- The error message and the fact that I assert that there is a GPU makes me think I've set up the Dataproc cluster with a GPU correctly.
- In the past I've seen this error when multiple PyTorch processes are trying to share the GPU. So what I've tried to fix it is change the `spark.executor` config to ensure that two executors aren't sharing the GPU but so far I haven't been able to configure it such that I avoid this error.

Any help/input would be much appreciated. Thanks!